# How is it possible that Ember's service() function knows the key it is called at?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

A question from curiosity. I analyze some Ember app for the first time and I met such a code:

```
export default Service.extend({
  api: service(),
  router: service(),
  flashes: service(),
  intercom: service(),
  store: service()
  // ...
})
```

As I can see, the `service` function here is clever enough to return adequate results for every key it is called at. And my question is: how is it possible? I thought that I know JavaScript, but I have no idea how it could be implemented. JavaScript functions know only their arguments and `this` object they are called for, don't they?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell [from the API docs](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.1/functions/@ember%2Fservice/inject) and [from the source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v4.1.0/packages/%40ember/-internals/metal/lib/injected_property.ts#L31) this is able to work because you're calling `service()` on a special type of object which has what Ember calls an 'owner'. When the service gets called it can use the objects owner to lookup the name of the property and determine the name of the service. I might be reading this wrong, I'm like 50% confident.

Comment: I believe that's actually the decorator (newer) implementation of `inject()`--here is the version that matches OP's pre-Octane syntax: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v3.9.1/packages/@ember/-internals/metal/lib/injected_property.ts